# how to generate recovery ID used in v of the signature

Tags: blockchain, polygon, openethereum

hope you guys are doing well.

I found the same question asked by someone else, which was quite hard to understand but in this case, I'm using an unknown device to sign I know it's using **secp256k1**, and I might be able to get the curve order.

So having Curve order `n` and two parameters of the signature `r` & `s`, how can I generate `recoveryID` used for generating v of the signature, which is `v=chainID*2+35+recoveryID`

Have not found good documentation for it. Any help is appreciated.

> Note: recoveryID is 0 or 1 as far as I got to know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: by the way I'm trying to do it with dart so the algorithm used by dart libs would be much more helpfull

Comment: How are the r and s parameters computed? Usually the signature process should produce the three parameters r, s and v. As a workaround try verifying both possible signatures (r,s,0) and (r,s,1), one of them should succeed.

Comment: Well my signature is der format of ecdsa sig so it only has r and s which is in a '30450220RRRRRRRRR0220SSSSSSS'format which the30450220 stuff shows the signature length s and r length. to generate v parity bit of Ry is needed which you can not find within a der format signature so signature verification is used to see if v is 0 or 1 that as far as i know dart does not have such library and v is not defined in any of the libraries existing.

Comment: web3dart has an ecRecover that you can use, see https://pub.dev/documentation/web3dart/latest/crypto/ecRecover.html.

Comment: That was really helpful @Ismael but as far as I understand 
`if (header < 27 || header > 34) {`
    `throw Exception('Header byte out of range: $header');`
  `}`
this part of the code means that it can't be used for Ethereum chains with a v greater than 35 which is used in eip155.

Comment: The parity is adjusted before with `header = signatureData.v & 0xFF`. If you tweak the `v` parameter to the value expected by Ethereum 0 -> 0x1b, 1 -> 0x1c it should work. The other option is to submit a PR to web3dart repo.

Comment: @Ismael thanks for your support it really helped I did the tweaking thingy before even you said and it worked. Doing so I stump upon a point it was: as you might know recID must be flipped if s>q/2 where q is curve order its also known as n and then s must be equal to q-s, here is the tricky part if you do the q-s part first and then try to find the recovery id from web3 ecRecover there is no need to flip the recID and it will be 0 if v=27 gives the corresponding publicKey and it will be 1 if v=28 gives the corresponding publicKey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank to @ismael I developed the code in a rookie clean way you can find it in git repo: [here](https://github.com/nimashahahmadian/Dart-Transaction-Script)
and I'm also going to describe a bit of code here too.

```
var maxValueForS = BigInt.parse('FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141', radix: 16);
var treshHoldForS = BigInt.parse('7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF5D576E7357A4501DDFE92F46681B20A0', radix: 16);
if (s > treshHoldForS) {
  s = maxValueForS - s;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  var sig = MsgSignature(r, s, 27 + i);
  try {
    String pk = HexUtils.byteArrayToHexString(ecRecover(HexUtils.hexStringToByteArray(trx.trxHash!), sig));
    if (pk.substring(0, 64) == mypublicKey) {
      recID = (recID + i) % 2;
    }
var v = chainID * 2 + 35 + recID;
```

this is all you need to get recID of a transaction signature and calculate the `v` from a derFormat signature.

Comment: Nice, good work!